# how to convert oracle PL/SQL using UTL_MAIL.send to email within PL/SQL to postgresql PL/SQL code?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, plsql

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sendmail(
p_from text,
p_to text,
p_subject text,
p_content text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

Comment: oracle code PROCEDURE send_error_mail IS      
       UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'donotreply@' || v_host_name,
                     recipients => v_dist_list,
                     subject => 'Partition '
                     message => 'Please query table')

Comment: there was a link posted about email from postgres, but the link does not work